# Extract exact part of the text in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column with the following type of text in it:

```
256 items delivered by supplier (LLC Printlogic)<br>
436 items delivered by supplier (LLC Mango)<br>
500 items shipped to supplier (Arteco Inc)<br>
```

How to extract value in the brackets? The result should be the following:

```
LLC Printlogic<br>
LLC Mango<br>
Arteco Inc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to parse text. Here is one of them.

```
=REPLACE(REPLACE(A2, FIND(")", A2), LEN(A2), ""),1, FIND("(", A2), "")
```

[image: replace_parse]

Answer (score 0):

one alternative,

```
=MID(A1,FIND("(",A1)+1,FIND(")",A1)-FIND("(",A1)-1)&"<br>"
```

Answer (score 0):

And another, that assumes the characters at the end are enclosed in `<...>` but not might always be `<br>`

```
=SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(A1,1,FIND("(",A1),""),")","")
```

[image]

Note that that same formula will also work on your original post, before it was edited and the `<br>` added at the end of each line:

[image]